# Add classes within ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

How do I add different classes for the inner elements in an ngFor loop in Angular 4? Say, I have a snippet:

```
<div *ngFor="let article of articles">
  <div>
    <h3>{{article.name}}</h3>
    <p>{{article.body}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I have 2 questions: how do I add different classes to the h3 elements in every generated article based on their order (first, second, third) and how do I add classes to the h3 elements based on odd-even order?

Comment: just as a side note : you are setting the same id for all your loop divs, namely the string `"article"`, which could get you into other errors.

Comment: Thanks, that actually shouldn't be there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the index, odd, and even of the current iteration in the [ngForOf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf), combine that with [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) and you can set the class.

```
<div *ngFor="let article of articles; index as i; even as isEven; odd as isOdd">
  <div id="article">
    <h3 [ngClass]="{'odd': isOdd, 'even': isEven}">{{article.name}}</h3>
    <p>{{article.body}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You do not mention how you want to use the index/position so there is no code for that. I am sure you can figure that part out though based on the sample code above and documentation.

---

As @Paco0 also pointed out maybe you meant `id="article"` to be `id="{{article.id}}"` or something similar?

Comment: isEven is default function?

Comment: as long as id is just an html attribute, "article.id" will be the string `"article.id"`, not the actual article id.  Need something like `id="{{article.id}}"` to be evaluated.

Comment: @artgb - no, `even` is and `isEven` is an alias for `even`.

Comment: Thanks, make sense